# Can't reference Views from layout in code

Tags: java, android

I have a simple layout with two TextViews and two Buttons.  In my java source, I want to set an OnClickListener to the Buttons, but when I attempt to do so, I get a NullPointerException, despite the fact that the buttons are defined in the layout.  I have slightly modified the code to prevent a runtime error and instead output information to the LogCat.  Below is the code and layout:

```
package com.jz.myapp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i("db", "R.id.b1: " + findViewById(R.id.b1).toString() + " R.id.b2: " + findViewById(R.id.b2));

        //This generates a NullPointerException, so it is commented out
        //Log.i("db", "b1: " + b1.toString() + " b2: " + b2.toString());

        /*
        When this code runs, it is reported that b1 and/or b2 are null,
        despite the fact that they are both defined in activity_main.xml.
        For this reason, the OnClickListner is never set for the buttons.
        What is the problem?
         */
        if ((b1==null) || (b2==null))
        {
            Log.i("db", "b1 and/or b2 are null");
        }
        else
        {
            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
            b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.b1)
        {
            tv2.setText("You have chosen Choice #1");
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.b2)
        {
            tv2.setText("You have chosen Choice #2");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.jz.myapp1.MainActivity"
    android:background="#0e1c67">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Let&apos;s Get Shit Working!"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:textColor="#ec1f1f" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choice #1"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choice #2"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fun Stuff Will Happen Here!"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#fa1212"
        android:background="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the LogCat output for the label "db":
07-16 14:24:35.330 12013-12013/com.jz.myapp1 I/db: R.id.b1: android.widget.Button{e714a19 VFED..C.. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0c0051 app:id/b1} R.id.b2: android.widget.Button{3265ade VFED..C.. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0c0052 app:id/b2}
07-16 14:24:35.330 12013-12013/com.jz.myapp1 I/db: b1 and/or b2 are null

without the conditional evaluation if ((b1==null) || (b2==null)), when 
b1.setOnClickListener(this) or b2.setOnClickListener(this) are called a NullPointerException is thrown.  I don't understand what the problem is, as both b1 and b2 are clearly defined in the layout xml.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project once, may help

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, you're getting your references to Button 1 and Button 2 *before* calling `setContentView` on the Activity.

You haven't set a layout yet, so clearly they don't exist yet. :)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.  I guess I misunderstood how findViewById() works :).